# Multiple thread to print numbers

Tags: java

I'm a student trying to learn Java. I want to print employee ID from 1 to 100 using three threads. I used the code that is shown below.

## My main class:

```
public class MainThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintThread pr = new PrintThread();
        Thread T1 = new Thread(pr);
        Thread T2 = new Thread(pr);
        Thread T3 = new Thread(pr);
        T1.start();
        T2.start();
        T3.start();
    }
}

public class PrintThread extends Thread {

    private final Object sync = new Object();

    public void run() {
        synchronized (sync) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 101; i++) {
                System.out.println("Employee ID : " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
 }
```

I'm getting output as 1....100 is printed by thread 1 then again by thread 2 and thread 3.

But my intended output is thread 1 printing one,thread 2 printing 2,thread 3 printing 3 and so on.

Please help me to sort this out.!!!

Comment: You'll need to tell each thread which numbers to print.  For example, add a parameter `int p` and only print `i` if `i % p == 0`.  Omitting the test and always incrementing by the number of threads will of course be more efficient.

Comment: So how should i change my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.  The most fundamental one is probably that your threads are not told what portion of the work to do.  If you want to split the work up into chunks for each task, you'd have to tell each thread what portion of the work to do.  Since you have stated that you want thread 1 produce output 1, 4, 7, …, we'd tell each thread where to start, where to stop and how much to advance the counter in each iteration.

Before I'll show the code for this, let's look at some other problems that need fixing.  Your synchronization is also flawed for two reasons.  First, every `PrintThread` has its own `sync` monitor.  Therefore, the locking is useless.  You'll need a monitor that is shared by all threads that need to be synchronized.

Second, you've put the entire loop (including the `sleep`) inside the `synchronized` block.  This means that if the monitor was properly shared between the threads, the program would be essentially sequential.  Usually, we only want to synchronize *as little as possible* in order to keep concurrency at a maximum.  In your case, the only thing that really needs synchronization is the printing (so not to mess up single unrelated lines of output, eg get `"12\n3\n"` instead of `"1\n23\n"`).  In such a case, we want to use the concurrent object as a monitor.  Here, we could pass the `PrintStream` to the constructor and use it as a monitor.

Another thing that needs attention is your handling of the `InterruptedException`.  Such exception is thrown to signal to a thread that we (whoever that is) have lot interest in its operation so if it please were so kind as to exit gracefully at its earliest convenience.  The proper handling of catching an `InterruptedException` is therefore to clean up what needs cleaning and then return as quickly as possible.

Finally, it is not good style to inherit from `Thread`.  Instead, implement `Runnable` and pass instances of your class to the constructor of `Thread`. (But if you *do* inherit from `Thread`, then don't wrap that instance into yet *another* `Thread`.)

Putting all this together, we get the following:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class PrintingTask implements Runnable {

    private final PrintStream stream;
    private final int first;
    private final int last;
    private final int incr;

    public PrintingTask(final PrintStream stream,
                        final int first,
                        final int last,
                        final int incr) {
        if (stream == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("stream");
        }
        this.stream = stream;
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.incr = incr;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = this.first; i <= this.last; i+= this.incr) {
            synchronized (this.stream) {
                this.stream.println(i);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can use it like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final int nthreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    final Thread[] workers = new Thread[nthreads];
    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i) {
        workers[i] = new Thread(new PrintingTask(System.out, i + 1, 100, nthreads));
    }
    for (final Thread t : workers) {
        t.start();
    }
    for (final Thread t : workers) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

It will print an arbitrary interleaving of lines with the numbers from 1 to 100 but each line itself will be printed atomically.  I hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you create all the threads with the same object, try it like this :

```
PrintThread pr1 = new PrintThread();
Thread T1 = new Thread(pr1);
PrintThread pr2 = new PrintThread();
Thread T2 = new Thread(pr2);
PrintThread pr3 = new PrintThread();
Thread T3 = new Thread(pr3);
T1.start();
T2.start();
T3.start();
```

And make i static something like this :

```
static AtomicInteger i = 0
```

And change you for loop to while loop some thing like:

```
while(i.getAndIncrement()<101){
    //DO your stuff
}
```

Comment: And how does this solve OPs question? These threads shouldn't print *every* number.

Comment: @Tom this is OP's problem "I'm getting output as 1....100 is printed by thread 1 then again by thread 2 and thread 3." and my answer solve this issue. My solution solve this issue! Who say threads shouldnt print every number?!

Comment: OP does: `But my intended output is thread 1 printing one,thread 2 printing 2,thread 3 printing 3 and so on.`.

Comment: @Tom you were right :) thanks, I didnot read that, after first what I read I realize this issue and I think jut that was the problem, but know I solve the other problem too.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by something like,

```
class A extends Thread{
    String name = "";
    static Integer num = 1;
    public void run(){
        while(num <= 100){

            synchronized(num){

                System.out.println(name + " " +num);
                num++;

            }

            try{
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}


        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A t1 = new A();
        t1.name = "Thread one";
        A t2 = new A();
        t2.name = "Thread two";
        A t3 = new A();
        t3.name = "Thread three";
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

What I have done is created a `static` variable which will be common for all the objects (threads) therefore they all will be printing one common value and incrementing it. This can be used to achieve what you want.

**NOTE:** I wrote it for just fun. You may want to edit the code as per your need. It is not perfect code as of now.

**Output**

```
Thread one 0
Thread three 1
Thread two 2
Thread one 3
Thread three 4
Thread two 5
Thread one 6
Thread three 7
Thread two 8
Thread one 9
Thread three 10
Thread two 11
```

Comment: @Tom I said that it's not perfect and it is kind of hint from my side. However I posted the output which I got from this. I didn't check all numbers.

Comment: At least start from `1` and not `0`.

Comment: @Tom For that the variable `num` in my code needs to be initialized from `1` rather than `0`. However I did it in the code but not in the output.

Comment: But when I try to print the thread Name using Thread.currentThread().getName() method it alaways returns Thread 1.So my thread 2 and 3 is not working in this casse ?

Comment: @SachinShaju How you are trying to do ? With my code? It shouldn't be the case with my code.

Comment: @SachinShaju `getName()` returns the name of the thread, this is not the same as the `name` field in this code. You can either change your code to `t1.setName("Thread one");` (the same applies to the other thread instances) or access the name by using `tx.name` instead of `tx.getName()` (with `x` as the thread number).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of 5 threads contending Counter object through synchronized keyword and the winner prints the next number until we print out all 100 numbers.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Counter counter = new Counter(100);
        CounterTask counterTask = new CounterTask(counter);

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(counterTask);
            threads[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            threads[i].join();
        }
    }
}

class Counter {
    private int n;
    private int i;

    public Counter(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        i = 0;
    }

    public synchronized int getNext() {
        if (i >= n) return -1;

        i++;
        return i;
    }
}

class CounterTask implements Runnable {
    Counter counter;
    public CounterTask(Counter counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (counter) {
                int next = counter.getNext();
                if (next == -1) break;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + next);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your threads are doing the same:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 101; i++) 
{
  System.out.println("Employee ID : " + i);
  try {
       Thread.sleep(100);
      } 
      catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

They all just print the numbers 1 to 100 because they all have their own for-loop and own variable.

You need to add a variable which all threads access, print and increment.

This variable has to be synchronized in order to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using the same `PrintThread pr` in all your threads. Because `pr` synchronizes for the duration of its run,  you see the output in sequence. To change that try

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread T1 = new Thread(new PrintThread());
    Thread T2 = new Thread(new PrintThread());
    Thread T3 = new Thread(new PrintThread());
    T1.start();
    T2.start();
    T3.start();
  }
```

Comment: And how does this solve OPs question? These threads shouldn't print *every* number.